# Group occurrences and combine values for Line Chart

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I want to create a chart that counts occurrences from two different columns which might not have the same values.

Here is a sample data:

[image: Example table]

*Be aware that the unique values might not be the same in each column (in this example, "Start Week" does not have "5")*

The expected result is similar to the image below:

[image: Result]

The straight line is for "Start Week" and the squiggly one is for "Finish Week".

This appears to be a simple task, but I've struggled a lot in my attempts.

Answer (score 1):

[image: grahic]

If this result is good for you, see [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qmHQgwS0XvDbdHTZTXYtPjBLasynZj8JtW7htys2R_I/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This is the expected result but the solution seems a bit complicated  I hoped that extra tables were not necessary...